# Why is SDL_RenderCopy so long?

Tags: c, sdl

I'm creating a game with SDL2 in C and I have a problem, I'm actually doing the main menu of my game: I have 3 buttons on my menu and I want them to go red when I put my mouse over them, so what I did is I pre-loaded 4 SDL_Textures for my entire screen: one with all buttons not colored and the 3 others are the same main menu with each button highlighted in red, I thought it would be faster than changing the button color and recreating the texture each time, but when I put my mouse over the buttons they are passing red really slow, I'm just using SDL_RenderCopy and SDL_RenderPresent each time the screen is updated so it shouldn't be that long. Here's my function code and a picture of my program to understand better. (sorry for the bad english btw)

[image]

```
typedef struct          s_sdlVar
{
    SDL_Window          *window;
    SDL_Renderer        *renderer;
    SDL_Event           event;
    SDL_Texture         *mainMenu[MAIN_MENU_TEXTURE_COUNT];
    t_rect              mainMenuButtonRect[MAIN_MENU_OPTION_COUNT];
    t_res               screenResolution;
    int                 boxSiz;
    t_byte              difficulty;
}                       t_sdlVar;

static int  checkButtonPos(t_rect *buttonPos, int x, int y)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < MAIN_MENU_OPTION_COUNT; i++)
        if ((x >= buttonPos[i].x) && (x < buttonPos[i].x + buttonPos[i].w)
        && (y >= buttonPos[i].y) && (y < buttonPos[i].y + buttonPos[i].h))
            return (i + 1);
    return (0);
}

int         displayMainMenu(t_sdlVar *sdl)
{
    t_bool  exit = false;
    t_bool  isButtonOn = false;
    int     textureIndex = 0, buttonIndex = 0;

    if (SDL_RenderCopy(sdl->renderer, sdl->mainMenu[0], NULL, NULL))
        return (-1);
    SDL_RenderPresent(sdl->renderer);
    while (!exit)
        if (SDL_PollEvent(&sdl->event))
        {
            if (sdl->event.type == SDL_MOUSEMOTION)
            {
                if ((textureIndex = checkButtonPos(sdl->mainMenuButtonRect, sdl->event.motion.x, sdl->event.motion.y)))
                {
                    if (SDL_RenderCopy(sdl->renderer, sdl->mainMenu[textureIndex], NULL, NULL))
                        return (-1);
                    SDL_RenderPresent(sdl->renderer);
                    isButtonOn = true;
                }
                else if (isButtonOn)
                {
                    if (SDL_RenderCopy(sdl->renderer, sdl->mainMenu[0], NULL, NULL))
                        return (-1);
                    SDL_RenderPresent(sdl->renderer);
                    isButtonOn = false;
                }
            }
            else if ((sdl->event.type == SDL_QUIT) || ((sdl->event.type == SDL_MOUSEBUTTONDOWN) && isButtonOn && (textureIndex == 2)))
                exit = true;
        }
    return (buttonIndex);
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling `SDL_RenderPresent()` all the time?  Do that once at the end of the frame.

Comment: Because if I call it once it will call the function even when there is nothing to render

Comment: Could it be my mac which is too slow? It's a 2012 but I thought a main menu wouldn't be that ressourceful

Comment: Shouldn't you use SDL_WaitEvent if you aren't going to do anything until an event comes?

Comment: Don't render anything from the event handling code! Only save the mouse position (or whatever), then after the event loop draw all your things and call `SDL_RenderPresent()`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I use a loop because if the mouse goes on another button it needs to update to the next button

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, can you elaborate?